# Como obter os dados do produto com JavaScript, ajax e PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Olá, não estou conseguindo trazer os dados dos produtos para a `<div id="services"></div>`.

Reparei que quando retiro essa parte do código `?codsubcategoria='.$res2['nome'].'` da `<li class="teste"></li>`, me traz pelo menos as tabelas de Marcas e Categorias.

Acredito que esteja faltando algo no Javascript, mas não faço ideia do que, e de como posso solucionar esse problema.
Conto com a ajuda dos amigos.

Abaixo relaciono os códigos usados.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#menu_cat .teste a").click(function( e ){
        e.preventDefault();
        var href = $( this ).attr("href");
        $("#services").load( href +"#services");
    });
});
```

```
<ul id="menu_cat">
<?php
include "../conexao.php";
$codigo = $_POST['codigo'];
$nome_cat = $_POST['nome_cat'];
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT codigo, nome_cat FROM categoria ORDER BY nome_cat") or die(mysql_error());

while($res = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

    echo '<li><a href="#services">'.$res['nome_cat'].'</a>';

    $query2 = mysql_query("SELECT codigo, nome, nome_cat FROM sub_categoria WHERE nome_cat = '".$res['nome_cat']."' ORDER BY nome") or die(mysql_error());
    if(mysql_num_rows($query2) > 0) {
        echo '<ul id="menu_cat">';
        while($res2 = mysql_fetch_array($query2)) {
            echo '<li class="teste"><a href="prod_index_categoria.php?codsubcategoria='.$res2['nome'].'">'.$res2['nome'].'</a></li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }

    echo '</li>';

}
?>
</ul>
```

Desde já meus agradecimentos pela a atenção ao meu problema.

Comment: Não ficou muito claro o que deseja...

Comment: Como você trata a requisição da uri prod_index_categoria.php?codsubcategoria=xxxx ? E realmente no javascript você chama prod_index_categoria.php?codsubcategoria=xxx#service? Por que? Uma dica quando você faz requisições ajax é sempre bom usar as ferramentas de debug do navegador para ver os parametros enviados e recebidos (Na maioria dos navegadores botão direito - inspecionar elemento - aba network).

Comment: Estou tentando carregar o conteúdo dinamicamente em uma div na index sem o refresh. Se quiser posso enviar o endereço para que verifique o que eu desejo testando diretamente no Site.

Comment: Manda o endereço, ou especifique o que deseja fazer e como detalhadamente, pois no código fica mais complicado entender.

Comment: Olá @Cleverson, o endereço é (http://vogadesignglass.com). entre em produtos e quando você clica em qualquer uma das marcas ele funciona do jeito desejado, ou seja abrindo os produtos referente a marca selecionada sem dar o refresh no Site na **DIV id="services"** que se encontra na index.php. Já quando é selecionado o produto referente a Categorias desejada,  ele vai para a DIV, porém não abre nem mesmo as tabelas de Marcas e Categorias.

Comment: Continuando - Como informei anteriormente, quando retiro essa parte do código **?codsubcategoria='.$res2['nome'].'** da **<li class="teste"></li>**, me traz pelo menos as tabelas de Marcas e Categorias. Se você puder me dar uma luz de como solucionar isso ficarei muito agradecido.